# ¿Cómo puedo comprobar si existe un activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una aplicación android en la que cuando doy logout por ejemplo, me manda a login pero obviamente no tengo que poder regresar al main activity, mi problema es que debido a unas animaciones tengo que cerrar las activity desde la siguiente con un `getInstance()`, eso lo he puesto en el `onTransitionEnd()`, pero si una de las activity que cierro nunca ha sido abierta tiene errores, no sé cómo hacer una condición para que solo cierre las que han abierto.

Así se cierran las `Activity`:

```
explode.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            MainActivity.getInstance().finish();
            ChangePassActivity.getInstance().finish();
            TermsConditionsActivity.getInstance().finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes validar si la instancia es diferente de null, en base a esto proceder a cerrarla

```
if(MainActivity.getInstance() !=  null){
  MainActivity.getInstance().finish();
}
if(ChangePassActivity.getInstance() !=  null){
   ChangePassActivity.getInstance().finish();
}
if(TermsConditionsActivity.getInstance() !=  null){
   TermsConditionsActivity.getInstance().finish();
}
```